# Oracle: Create function to update records based on parameter

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Given a table with amount and type:

```
| AMOUNT | PAY_TYPE |
| 0.50   | D        |
| 0.50   | D        |
| 0.50   | D        |
| 0.10   | D        |
| 0.50   | D        |
| 0.50   | D        |
```

I'm trying to write a function with input parameter (amount) which updates  pay_type from 'D' to 'A' for the rows with sum equal to the passed parameter.

For example, if I pass 2.50 to function, the result should look like this:

```
| AMOUNT | PAY_TYPE |
| 0.50   | A        |
| 0.50   | A        |
| 0.10   | D        |
| 0.50   | A        |
| 0.50   | A        |
| 0.50   | A        |
```

Also the problem is if I pass to the function 2.40 than function should split one row in two parts and only after that update table.

Comment: How do you decide which rows should be used "first"? In your example, you left the 0.10 row for last - do you use the rows in decreasing order of their amount? Do the rows also have other values (other columns in the table) by which you can distinguish them from each other? And what should the result be if the variable passed in is more than the sum of all values in the table?

Comment: @mathguy the passed value will never be more than the sum.

Comment: Ans also it does not matter which row will be updated first, the goal is to update all rows with sum equal to passed value .

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent illustration of the power of the `MERGE` statement. We need to update some rows, possibly delete one row (the row that must be split if the total amount is not the exact sum of rows selected) and insert two rows (again, to replace the "split" row).

Writing the statement the way I did requires Oracle 11.2 since I used a `WITH` clause with column names given in the declaration; but this can be rearranged easily (using an inline view) for older versions of Oracle.

The solution doesn't require a function, or PL/SQL of any kind (although of course it can be wrapped within a function if needed). It's all pure SQL.

In my solution I used `rowid` as a substitute for a proper primary key. It would be MUCH better if the base table had a PK which could be used instead of `rowid`.

I didn't show how the bind variable is given a value. In my case, I ran this in SQL Developer; whenever you try to run a statement with bind variables in SQL Developer, a window pops up for the input. (I believe Toad is similar.) Each front-end program will have its own mechanism for assigning values to bind variables.

**Preparation**

```
create table inputs as
       select 0.50 amount, 'D' pay_type from dual union all
       select 0.50, 'D' from dual union all
       select 0.50, 'D' from dual union all
       select 0.10, 'D' from dual union all
       select 0.50, 'D' from dual union all
       select 0.50, 'D' from dual
;

commit;

select * from inputs; 

AMOUNT  PAY_TYPE
------  --------
   0.5  D
   0.5  D
   0.5  D
   0.1  D
   0.5  D
   0.5  D
```

**`MERGE` statement**

```
merge into inputs i
  using (
    with prep ( amount, pay_type, rn, l_amt, c_amt ) as (
           select amount, pay_type, rowid as rn,
                  coalesce(sum(amount) over (order by rowid 
                     rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0),
                  sum(amount) over (order by rowid)
           from   inputs
         )
    select  amount, pay_type, rn, c_amt
      from  prep
      where l_amt < :input_value
    union all
      select  :input_value - l_amt, 'A', null, null
        from  prep
        where :input_value > l_amt and :input_value < c_amt
    union all
      select  c_amt - :input_value, 'D', null, null
        from  prep
        where :input_value > l_amt and :input_value < c_amt
  ) x
  on (i.rowid = x.rn)
when matched
  then update set i.pay_type = 'A'
       delete where :input_value < c_amt
when not matched
  then insert values (x.amount, x.pay_type)
;

7 rows merged.
```

**Outcome**

```
select * from inputs;

AMOUNT  PAY_TYPE
------  --------
   0.5  A
   0.5  A
   0.5  A
   0.1  A
   0.5  A
   0.1  D
   0.4  A
```